# How could I reference a model to my User model with Express/Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, mongoose

I have two models, one being my User model and the other being my Course model. I would like to have it so when a User (Teacher) creates a course, it assigns that course to them and vice versa. Here are my models to explain better:

Course Schema/Model:

```
var CourseSchema = new Schema({
    courseID: {
        type: Number,
        unique: true
    },
    courseName: String,
    courseDesc: {
        type: String,
        default: "No course description provided."
    },
    coursePicture: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    teacher: [
        {
           type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
           ref: 'User'
        }
    ],
    students: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Student'
         }
    ]
})
```

User Schema/Model:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  email: String,
  courses: [
    {
       type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref: 'Course'
    }
  ], 
  password: String
});
```

Basically, I want to have it so on my frontend, I could do things like course.teacher.firstName or user.courses. My schemas are in two different files, but I believe that is fine. It's like assigning a user a post when they create it. I don't know how I could do this, as I've tried multiple things.

Right now, I currently have this for creating a course.

```
// Creates a new course
router.post('/create', function (req, res) {
    Course.create({
            courseID : req.body.courseID,
            courseName : req.body.courseName,
            courseDesc : req.body.courseDesc,
            coursePicture : req.body.coursePicture,
            teacher : req.body.id,
            students: req.body.students
        }, 
        function (err, course) {
            if (err) return res.status(500).send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
            res.status(200).send(course);

        });
});
```

I have already referenced the User model in the controller where that code ^ belongs as so var User = require('../user/User'); 
I believe that is needed to pull this off. If you have any questions, please let me know as I'm not the best at explaining things like this.

Hope someone can help me out!

Thanks.

Comment: So whats the problem?

Comment: Sorry I should probably rephrase this. I don't have a problem, I just don't know how I would link a Course to a User(Teacher) and link the User(Teacher) to the Course so I could use fields as mentioned in the post: course.teacher.firstName or user.courses

Comment: This is a good question. I have provided a comprehensive answer with some tips for database design in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Creates a new course
router.post('/create', function (req, res) {
    Course.create({
            courseID : req.body.courseID,
            courseName : req.body.courseName,
            courseDesc : req.body.courseDesc,
            coursePicture : req.body.coursePicture,
            teacher : req.body.id, // find this user
            students: req.body.students,
            attendance: req.body.attendance 
        }, 
        function (err, course) {
            User.findById(req.body.id, function(err, user) {
                user.update({
                    $push: {
                        courses: course._id
                    }
                }, function(err) {
                     if (err) return res.status(500).send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
                     res.status(200).send(course);
                })
            })
        });
});
```

Comment: I tried this out and it does work, but not with what I want to do since I would like to reference things like user.courses.courseName or something. This only puts the ID and I assume having it send the whole course object isn't the greatest idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of database design. There should only be one place where information about a course is stored, the Courses table, and the Users table should know nothing about courses. There should be a table the relates a course to a user: a UserCourseRelations table.

I would strongly avoid the approach of storing an array of courseIds that a user is related in the user table as this is unnecessary coupling and so is not good database design. Also, it'll bog down reads to your Users table as those arrays grow on every row.

Here's how I would approach this. Note that some of this code uses ES6 syntax. The following code is untested, but should work. Take a look:

Create CourseSchema and CourseModel

```
var CourseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    courseID: {
        type: Number,
        unique: true
    },
    courseName: String,
    courseDesc: {
        type: String,
        default: "No course description provided."
    },
    teacherId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    }
    coursePicture: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    students: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Student'
        }
    ]
})

CourseSchema.statics.createNew = function(data, callback) {
    // do some verification here

    // insert the new course
    return new this(data).save((err, dbCourse) => {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err)
        }

        UserCourseRelationSchema.insertNew('teacher', userId, courseID, (err, dbUserCourseRelation) => {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err)
            }

            // done. return the new course
            callback(null, dbCourse)
        })
    })

    CourseSchema.statics.getByIds = function(courseIDs, callback) {
        // find all of the courses where the courseID is in the courseIDs array
        // see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/
        this.find({courseID: {$in: courseIDs}}, (err, courses) => {
            if (err) {
                // something went wrong
                return callback(err)
            }
            callback(null, courses)
        })
    }
}

let CourseModel mongoose.model('courses', CourseSchema);
```

Create UserCourseRelationSchema and UserCourseRelationModel that relates a course to a user and vice versa

```
var UserCourseRelationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
    userId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    courseID: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    type: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['teacher', 'student'],
        required: true,
    },
});

UserCourseRelationSchema.statics.createNew = function(type, courseID, userId, callback) {
    // do some verification here. I suggest making sure this relation doesn't already exist

    // insert the new course
    return new this({
        courseID: courseID,
        userId: userId,
        type: type,
    }).save((err, dbUserCourseRelation) => {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err)
        }

        // return the new relation
        callback(null, dbRelation)
    })
}

UserCourseRelationSchema.statics.getTeacherRelationCourseIdsByUserId = function(userId, callback) {
    let query = this.find({userId: userId, type: 'teacher'})
    query.distinct('courseID') // get an array of only the distinct courseIDs
    query.exec((err, courseIDs) => {
        if (err) {
            // something went wrong
            return callback(err)
        }
        callback(null, courseIDs)
    })
}

let UserCourseRelationModel = mongoose.model('user_course_relations', UserCourseRelationSchema);
```

Create UserSchema and UserModel

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    password: String
});

UserSchema.statics.getAllCoursesById = function(userId, callback) {
    // get the relations for the courses the user is a teacher of
    UserCourseRelationModel.getTeacherRelationCourseIdsByUserId(userId, (err, courseIDs) => {
        // get the courses by the returned coursIDs
        CourseModel.getByIds(courseIDs, (err, courses) => {
            if (err) {
                // something went wrong
                return callback(err)
            }
            callback(nul, courses)
        })
    })
}

let UserModel = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);

// -- create the router

// Creates a new course
router.post('/create', function (req, res) {
    CourseModel.createNew({
        courseID : req.body.courseID,
        courseName : req.body.courseName,
        courseDesc : req.body.courseDesc,
        coursePicture : req.body.coursePicture,
        teacher : req.body.id,
        students: req.body.students
    }, function (err, course) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
        res.status(200).send(course);
    });
});

 // -- done
```

I also suggest using promises if possible as it makes all of this logic much simpler.

Comment: Mongodb is noSql database, it doesn't have relation, but subdocument

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for the response. I am unfamiliar with ES6 syntax and am actually a beginner with this whole Node/Express/Mongoose stuff. Are these changes really necessary to achieve what I want to do? I was taking a look at this [link](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-to-assign-a-user-a-post-with-mongoose-and-express) and I feel like all these changes aren't really needed. I am no expert though, it's just difficult to understand what you have done.

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly "relation" is not a concept reserved by sql. Relationships are something you can implement however you'd like. What I have shown in my answer is one way to implement an relation. This is a matter of database design, not technology. As I said, if you go down the road of coupling your tables heavily, queries will becoming increasingly expensive.

Comment: @omar These changes are not necessary, but I strongly advise them if you don't want to be banging your head against a wall in the near future. The only new syntax here are the arrow functions () => and destructuring assignments. Your server should have ES6, but if it doesn't let me know and I can adjust the syntax in my answer for you.

Comment: @lwdthe1 I would appreciate that. Do you have Discord or something so we could chat so I could discuss this more with you as I still have a few questions regarding this

Comment: Actually, I am stupid. ES6 works fine, but I still have a few questions on what to do and how I could organize this, so if you have a way where I can chat directly with you, I'd appreciate it. Thank you.